# R Markdown questions

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, pandoc

I am an absolute beginner in R markdown. I have no previous knowledge of `LaTeX`, `Markdown` or `knitr`. Using the markdown quick reference in rstudio Version 0.98.501 I created a document which looks exactly like I wanted. Following are my questions:

If I only use Rmd file (i.e. File > New File > R Markdown) can I still compile a Pdf file? I could only see knit HTML. I tried installing pandoc and used following:

```
# Set working directory
setwd("C:/Users/durraniu/Documents/Trajectory1/knitHtml")

# Load packages
require(knitr)
require(markdown)

system("pandoc -s Trajectory1.html -o Trajectory1.pdf")
```

Although there was no warning/ error in rstudio but there was no file generated.

1. How can I create pdf of my file? The second part of this question
   is: How can I create a word document out of it?
2. I am going to do several analyses on a big file (about 200 mb) and
   it took rstudio about 10 minutes to knit the file with one analysis
   I've done so far. If I append the file with more analyses it would
   take forever to knit it. Why doesn't rstudio remember what has
   already been processed to html? Or am I missing something?
3. How can I cite references and add bibliography in R Markdown, if
   there is any option for that?

Comment: Use the `cache` option in the code chunk header, and `set.seed` to make it knit faster

Comment: To make a PDF you need to have a version of LaTeX installed on your computer. To make a word doc you only need pandoc. As Richard says, use `cache` in your code chunks to prevent time consuming computations for being redone every time you knit. See [here](http://quantifyingmemory.blogspot.com/2013/02/reproducible-research-with-r-knitr.html) for an example of how to add references and a bibliography

Comment: Check [the knitr page](http://yihui.name/knitr/) for exactly what all the options mean.

Comment: @RichardScriven and @Ben thanks. I got the `cache` part.

Comment: at a certain point, compiling a lot of analyses is going to be very labor intensive no matter what. Perhaps you could make a couple different .rmd files for sections of your analyses. The guy who does gforge did a great series on knitr and getting things into word, so you might read over that. It is much easier then going to pdf as opposed to the other way (pdf then to word).

Answer (score 1):

1. @Ben has it right, to create PDF you must have LaTeX installed (MiKTeX for windows, MacTeX for MacOS, TeXLive recommended for Linux). I don't remember RStudio giving you a button to knit into PDF, I typically use `pandoc(knit("file.Rmd"), format="latex")` to create a PDF. Replace "latex" with "docx" for word documents.
2. Both @Ben and @RichardScriven mentioned the use of `cache`. The content on the use of `set.seed` is to create reproducibility. (Google "reproducible research" for why this is important.) `set.seed` "ensures" that readers will be able to get the same response when using randomness.
3. The [pandoc user guide](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#citations) describes citations and bibliographies.